# What is setting the height of my column?

Tags: css, html

I am not a professional web-developer but I am designing one to help out a no-profit organization.
I spent a couple of days searching the web for instructions and explanations on css, float, position, etc. Finally I managed to design the layout I wanted with the behaviour I wanted but there is still something that is not working/I do not understand.
Please, see the page at: "http://www.missione-berna.ch/index2.php" and its source; I put all the code in it to make it accessible (at the end stiles, scripts, menu and header will be in separate files included eventually via php).
How come that my "Menu" div is neither the size of its content nor the size of the neighbour "Contenuto" div?
I understood that it is not an easy task to have the height of two div column match, but where is this "mid-way" size coming from?
Any help appreciated, thansk in advance.

Comment: Check out http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks for details on how to make "simple" equal-height columns. It's a very very handy technique.

Comment: Thanks that is also useful; I still experimenting so to learn by doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `position: absolute` can be a Very Bad Thing. Avoid it unless trying to take elements out of the flow of the page (having one element appear on top of another).

Second, `height: 100%` does not do what, intuitively, you'd think it does. You're setting the height of the menu div to 100% of the *viewport's* height (your browser window), not 100% of the entire *page*.

Since your menu has a simple background, there's a neat trick you can use to make it appear to be the same height. [CSSDesk](http://cssdesk.com/8x2v8)

I've added a wrapper div around your menu and content. Relevant bits of HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="Fascione">
    <img id="FotoAngolare" alt="ChiesaEsterno" src="images/esterno.jpg" width="195" height="122">
    <div id="Impressum">
        <span class="Intestazione">Missione Cattolica Italiana</span><br>
        <span class="Titolo">Chiesa "Madonna degli Emigrati"</span><br>
        <span class="Testo">Bovetstrasse 1 - 3007 Bern<br>Tel. 031 371 0243 / Fax. 031 372 1656</span><br>
        <a class="Email" href="mailto:missione.berna@bluewin.ch">missione.berna@bluewin.ch</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="Menu">
    <a href="top"></a>
    <ul id="MenuList" class="Testo"></ul>
<div id="Contenuto">
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And styled it like so:

```
#wrap { background: #e8e8e8; }
#Menu {float:left; width:195px; }
#Contenuto { background: #fff; border-left: 2px solid black; margin-left: 196px; min-width:829px; padding: 1px 1px 1px 15px; }
```

So the entire thing has a gray background. Your menu is floated left (over the gray background). The contentuo div has a left margin of 192px to "clear" the menu, and has a white background to hide the gray. The wrapper and content divs, and thus the gray/white backgrounds, will expand to the size of your content.

A couple tips:

1. Be careful with `height: 100%`.
2. `float: left` or `float: right`
   inherently set `display: block`. You can't set `display: inline` on
   floated elements.

Comment: I would avoid giving this advice: *position: absolute is a Very Bad Thing. Avoid it whenever possible.*  There are plenty of occasions where `position:absolute;` is a good and necessary thing.

Comment: There is absolutely NOTHING wrong with using position:absolute and stating it's a very bad thing is a very bad thing.

Comment: ooops... I was not finished with the comment. I wanted to use float, but I did not want my "Contenuto" page to move under the menu when resizing the browser window to a smaller size. And also in that case my menu was not going down to 100%. Any hint on how give the "page" height to the divs? I tried also min-height with no help; how come that min-width works instead?

Comment: Jason, I know what you mean, but I've seen far too many web devs use absolute positioning like it's the best thing since sliced bread, and position *everything* absolutely. It takes things out of the flow of the page, which often breaks your page. But it's rather excellent when you want to take things out of the flow of the page :P. Edited to reflect, though. I suppose "avoid whenever possible" is rather harsh.

Comment: @rodedo, do you only want the contentuo div to scroll and the rest of the page to stay fixed? That can be done too! Also, it was going down to 100%--you just couldn't see it. The background was on the menu items, not the menu itself.

Comment: @primatology - I still disagree with your first line and that it it's somewhat misleading. I would delete it altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot primatology! it worked like a charm. And I think I mostly understood how it works except the "padding:1px 1px 1px 15px;". I like the 15px on the left (I was adding 17 in my previous version) but I do not understand why the other side need the 1px. I tried to remove it and optaind a 15px hight white line between "Fascione" and "Menu" as well. Can you explain me how this is working?

Comment: Oh yep, forgot I added that. It's a feature of CSS called [margin collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins). Basically, the `p` elements have a top margin of 15px. Due to margin collapsing, the 15px margin is instead "collapsed" and applied to the surrounding div, creating the 15px gap you see. If you apply a padding (even just 1px), you disable margin collapsing. You technically need the 1px padding on the top and bottom and the 17px on the left; I just threw in the 1px on the right, too.

Comment: OK, one more thing. Initially you wrote "The contentuo div has a left margin of 192px to "clear" the menu"; but the code you show uses the float:left property instead. I tried them both: the "float" version has the problem that if I resize the borwser window, the "contenuto" div will go below the "Menu". This is what I wanted to avoid by using the "position:absolute" property. Is there a problem in not having the "Contenuto" div float?

Comment: Oh my goodness, I completely misunderstood what you meant. I updated my code to *cause* that behavior. Simple fix: replace the float: left with a margin-left: 192px. That's reflected in my answer and the CSSDesk I linked to. Should do exactly what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to acomplish what you're trying to acomplish is to put everything in a wrapper div, like this:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="Fascione">...</div>
    <div class="Menu">...</div>
    <div class="Contenuto">...</div>
</div>
```

Then height: 100% on Menu and min-height on both Menu and Contenuto.

Comment: what shall be the "style" of the wrapper? and one more question, what is the effect of setting both height and min-height for Menu?

Comment: height: 100% should make it fill the parent div and min-height should make it no shorter than x pixels. I'll look at it later once again and check what's wrong.